# Using nested data with D3.js

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, nested

I am trying to display a beautiful line graph using D3. The problem I have is with the format of the data.

I have the following data (as an example):

```
var data = [
    {
      label: "name",
      data: [[14444123, 0.012321312],
             [14444123, 0.012321312],
             [14444123, 0.012321312], ...]
    },{
      label: "another name",
      data: [[14444123, 0.012321312],
             [14444123, 0.012321312],
             [14444123, 0.012321312], ...]
    }
];
```

Each entry contains the name of it as well as a data attribute with array of points (each point is represented as an array, where item[0] is x timestamp and item[1] is the value).

My problem is that it is not working correctly.

This is the D3 code I have as of now:

```
var w = options.width,
    h = options.height,
    p = options.padding,
    x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([options.ydomainstart, options.ydomainend])
        .range([h, 0]);

var vis = d3.select(options.element)
    .data(data)
   .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w + p * 2)
    .attr("height", h + p * 2)
   .append("svg:g");

vis.append("svg:line")
    .attr("stroke", '#808080')
    .attr("x1", p)
    .attr("x2", p)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", h - p);

vis.append("svg:line")
    .attr("stroke", '#808080')
    .attr("x1", p)
    .attr("x2", w)
    .attr("y1", h - p)
    .attr("y2", h - p);

var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
    .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", w - p)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return 15 + i*12; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return defaultColors[i % 5]; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.label;});

var lines = rules.data(function(d, i) {
        return d.data;
    })
   .append("svg:path")
    .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return defaultColors[i % 5]; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
    }));
```

The problem I have appears in this part of the code:

```
.x(function(d) {
    return x(d[0]);
})
.y(function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
}));
```

The data inside 'd' is NOT the point array [x, y] but instead each value inside each array.

Meaning, on first item, d contains the x coordinate, on second item, it has the y coordinate, on third item, it contains the x coordinate on next point and so on.

It's like it's recursively going into the array, and then again for each value inside.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There’s a few problems here.

First, you’re appending an svg:path element to an svg:text element. It seems to me like you’re trying to create an svg:g element with the class "rule", but your code defines the selection `rules` as a set of svg:text elements. Create the svg:g elements first, and then append svg:text elements:

```
var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "rule");

rules.append("svg:text")
    …
```

The second problem is that the data operator is evaluated once per group, rather than once per element. See the section ["Operating on Selections"](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) in the API reference for more details. You have one svg:svg element in `vis`, so you have one group in `rules`, and so your data function is only called once:

```
function(d, i) {
  return d.data;
}
```

Then, the resulting data elements are mapped to the `rules` selection… which already have defined data from the previous selectAll and append when they were created.

The simple fix is to use the [map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-map) operator rather than the data operator, which is evaluated once per element rather than once per group.

```
rules.append("svg:path")
    .map(function(d) { return d.data; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    …
```

Alternatively, you could pass the data directly to the line generator, but that requires you declaring the line generator ahead of time rather than inlining it:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

rules.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.data); })
    …
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Note that the `map` method has been deprecated in favour of `datum`.