# d3 JSON multiple line chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to make a plot with multiple lines on it from a JSON blob that looks like:

```
{"2007": [{"val":10, "mon":10}, {"val":20, "mon":11}, {"val":40, "mon":12}, ...],
 "2008": [{"val":20, "mon":8}, {"val":20, "mon":9}, {"val":40, "mon":10}, ...],
  ...
 "2012": [{"val":40, "mon":8}, {"val":50, "mon":9}, {"val":60, "mon":10}, ...]
}
```

The data is basically monthly totals for each year, with some years not having data for some months. I can't figure out exactly how to parse the data in d3 though. I tried various ways such as

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
 .interpolate("basis")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.mon); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.val); });

svg.selectAll(".line")
 .data(series)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", line);
```

But I can't seem to get the data into the SVG line. Any suggestions? Is there a better way to structure the JSON?

Comment: Where do the multiple lines come in? Are you trying to make one line per year?

Comment: Yup, want one line for each year.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked out in case anyone else runs across this problem. The trick is to pass a function that returns the values in the associative array in the "d" attribute of the path element.

```
  entries = d3.entries(data);

  var colors = d3.scale.category20()
    .domain(d3.keys(data));

  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.month) })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) });

  svg1.selectAll(".line")
    .data(entries)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    // function(d), not just line function 
    .attr("d", function(d){ return  line(d.value); })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return colors(d.key) });
```

Some help from this answer too: 
[Using nested data with javascript D3 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111584/using-nested-data-with-javascript-d3-problem)

Comment: where is svg1 defined?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the biggest problem here is that you're starting with an object, not an array. `d3.data` takes an array, not an object, so you might need your data set up like:

```
[
  [{"val":10, "mon":10}, {"val":20, "mon":11}, {"val":40, "mon":12}, ...],
  [{"val":20, "mon":8}, {"val":20, "mon":9}, {"val":40, "mon":10}, ...],
  ...
]
```

If you need to convert your current data to this format, look at [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_entries), which will give you an array with your key as well as your array of points:

```
[
  {
    key: "2008",
    value: [{"val":10, "mon":10}, {"val":20, "mon":11}, {"val":40, "mon":12}, ...]
  },
  { 
    key: "2008",
    value: [{"val":20, "mon":8}, {"val":20, "mon":9}, {"val":40, "mon":10}, ...]
  },
  ...
]
```

See this fiddle for a simple-case version of your graph, using the first data format above: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/kmmyc/

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think that the d3.entries() business might work out. I'm stil a bit stumped on how to parse it in d3, bu I think its heading in the proper direction.