# Groups and lines from nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw multiple svg lines (using D3.js) from a nested object structure like this:

```
data = [ 
{ Name: "jim", color: "blue", Points: [{x:0, y:5 }, {x:25, y:7 }, {x:50, y:13}] },
{ Name: "bob", color: "green", Points: [{x:0, y:10}, {x:25, y:30}, {x:50, y:60}] }
];

var line_gen = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
                .x(function(d){return d.x;})
                .y(function(d){return d.y;});
```

My first attempt, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111584/using-nested-data-with-javascript-d3-problem) was to use svg:g to represent the first nesting level, then access the second nesting level within the group to render the lines:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".linegroup")
.data(data).enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "linegroup")
.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color; })
.style("fill", "none");

g.selectAll(".line")
.data(function(d) { return d.Points;})
.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", line_gen);
```

But this did not render any lines. Instead, inside each group I got an empty path tag for each of the three data points. So apparently the shape of the data is causing problems.

```
<g class="linegroup" style="stroke: #0000ff; fill: none;">
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
    <path></path>
</g>
```

I did find one solution (will post as answer) that doesn't use groups, but I would still like to know why the group solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer, largely based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308779/d3-json-multiple-line-chart) except that it doesn't use d3.entries:

```
data = [ 
{ Name: "jim", color: "blue", Points: [{x:0, y:5 }, {x:25, y:7 }, {x:50, y:13}] },
{ Name: "bob", color: "green", Points: [{x:0, y:10}, {x:25, y:30}, {x:50, y:60}] }
];

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100)

var line_gen = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
                .x(function(d){return d.x;})
                .y(function(d){return d.y;});

svg.selectAll(".line")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line_gen(d.Points); })   // <<<
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .style("fill", "none");
```

The key approach here is to not return the line_gen function directly to the "d" attribute but to wrap it in another function that passes the correct nested array from the outer object.

See also this [great discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/w_rvbAOkp6c) on d3.entries vs. d3.values. d3.entries seems to be suggested a lot for similar problems but I don't think it really helps in my case.

Comment: I was just about to link to that answer. . .

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you want to draw a line for each element in your list -- nested selections are meant for cases where more levels exist. For example, if you had a list with lists as elements and each list element contained a set of paths (e.g. to group sets of curves), nested selections would be appropriate.

What's happening in your case is that d3 is generating a new path for each element of `Points` -- that is, one for each point.

Comment: oh I see. So it was appropriate in the linked question because they actually *wanted* a circle tag for each data point, whereas I want a single path tag for all data points on the line. It seems like an example of a [leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) where you have to know that SVG uses path mini-language as attribute rather than distinct tags to represent the points on a line.

Comment: Well, not entirely -- the question would be which data elements to treat separately. If you want to put points on a line, they are arguably not treated separately. I do agree that it can be confusing however.